# Post on twitter from my site

Tags: twitter, workflow

I have a site where I want to allows my Editors to post to **their** twitter account the blog post they just written.

How should I proceed?

Should I ask them to create their own application on twitter and then store to my database their secret and public keys?
Is this a safe approach?
There is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To understand, you want to allow your editors to tweet the blog post they wrote from your website to twitter?

If this is the case you can just include a tweet button.

https://support.twitter.com/articles/231474?lang=en

https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons

Hope that answered your question.

Jesse

Comment: yes, pretty much, but I want to tweet the post as soon as they save the blog post